# Windows 10 task scheduler errors "task not supported"

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

After updating to W10 I think task scheduler worked normally. Today I tried to open %windir%\system32\taskschd.msc /s and got a long list of errors that said "this version of task object is not supported or invalid" all being tasks made in W7 I guess. After escaping the messages all kinds of tasks "are not there" anymore, although when opening taskschd again the same thing happens. I am working on it and I succeeded in importing one of those tasks and comparing the xml. Hope someone has already found a good solution. Will update my findings.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using cmd:

```
C:\>schtasks /Query > tasks.txt
```

This command prints all configured tasks into a txt on your C: drive (or your current working directory). I used cmd as administrator I think that's neccessary. Afterwards you can delete all tasks which are wrong:

```
C:\>schtasks /Delete /TN "\ASUS\ASUS AI Suite II Execute" /F
ERFOLGREICH: Die geplante Aufgabe "\ASUS\ASUS AI Suite II Execute" wurde erfolgreich gelöscht.
```

I hope that works for you too.

Regards
Steffen

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had by way of word and excel to generate a batchfile for about twenty deletions. It said it did so succesfully but when running the query again I had the same result. These tasks are stuck someplace and not really recognized as such.

Comment: Did you add the /f at the End as well?  Without it wasn't working for mehr as well. I also had sometimes issues when the task planner was open. For the List i trink this is 'nornal' because a lot of thise tasks are from Windows Media Player.

Comment: Yes I did. Part of my batchfile:
schtasks /Delete /TN "DispatchRecoveryTasks" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "ehDRMInit" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "InstallPlayReady" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "mcupdate" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "mcupdate_scheduled" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "MediaCenterRecoveryTask" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "ObjectStoreRecoveryTask" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "OCURActivate" /F
schtasks /Delete /TN "OCURDiscovery" /F

Comment: Ah I see the problem is that you don't provide the "full path" to the task:
e.g. for the first line it would need to look like:
schtasks /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Windows\Media Center\DispatchRecoveryTasks" /F
This path is always printed on each section from the output of the schtasks /query.

Comment: Hmm I wonder if this would help because the commands were executed "succesfully". But I will try anyway.

Comment: I tried it and got the same "results". I then looked into the tasks folder and removed some tasks manualy, copying them to another drive and folder and then deleting them. Still same results. The batchfile reporting success, The msc showing the usual errors, the query still signaling them N/A